# Find all usages trees

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Is there a way to find all usages of a method with a given depth or having certain parameter type as argument?
Suppose there is a class

```
class MyDeepClass
{
 public void MyDeepMethod() {}
}
```

and I need to extend it with new parameter *IMyParameter*.
However parameter is available somewhere many "floors" above the invocation chain and I need to determine all the chains leading to MyDeepMethod().

With Find Usages/Find All References command VS will locate all immediate invocations, for example

```
class MyClassA
{
 public void Foo()
 {
   obj.MyDeepMethod();
 }
}

class MyClassB
{
 public void Foo()
 {
   obj.MyDeepMethod();
 }
}
```

where obj is of MyDeepestClass will list

- MyClassA
- MyClassB

Now I need to Find usages on these 2 methods which leads to more usages and so on. This grows exponentially.
At some point I would finally arrive at some class having parameter defined. The problem is that I would need to do that separately for each path. This is extremely tedious.
Think of it as a tree having deepest method in question as a root, and methods containing needed parameter (as a class field for example, or passed as a parameter) as leaves.

So basically I'm looking for some Find Usages Advanced command
"Find me all top methods that lead to MyDeepMethod of a MyDeepClass directly or indirectly having IMyParameter defined as argument or class field":

A->B->C->MyDeepMethod
D->MyDeepMethod
E->F->B->C->MyDeepMethod

Or at least "Find all usages with the give depth of MyDeepMethod".

Comment: Well... if you add the parameter, you will get errors on all the callers. Is that not good enough for some reason? There's nothing like what you describe, though, not built-in at least.

Comment: I need to estimate upfront of how much changes to anticipate. If it will involve like 20 places I may go for some Singleton object/Service Locator or something like that whence parameter will be read. But than I still will need to know who are the 
"possessors" of parameter to store parameter somewhere, so MyDeepestClass will read it from there. Into some static intermediate class maybe.

Comment: Have you tried to call "ReSharper | Inspect | Incoming Calls" on the MyDeepMethod declaration? It will show you the full call tree for this method.

Comment: No, will try, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Incoming Calls](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Call_Tracking.html) feature can help you in this case. It can help you to view and navigate through call chains in your code.
Let's consider this code:

```
class MyDeepClass
{
    public void MyDeepMethod() { }
}
class MyClassA
{
    MyDeepClass obj;
    public void Foo()
    {
        obj.MyDeepMethod();
    }
}

class MyClassB
{
    MyDeepClass obj;
    public void Foo()
    {
        obj.MyDeepMethod();
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new MyClassB().Foo();
    }
}
```

Call the `ReSharper | Inspect | Incoming Calls` on the `MyDeepMethod` declaration and you will get the following call tree

[image]

By the way, if you finally decide to add a parameter to the `MyDeepMethod` method, you can get ReSharper assistance to help you update the [whole call tree](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Change_Signature.html#call_tree).
Call the `Change Signature` refactoring (`ReSharper | Refactor | Change Signature`) on the `MyDeepMethod` method declaration and add a new parameter in the dialog box:

[image]

Then click Next | Select `Resolve with call tree` opinion here | Click Next

[image]

And you get the step by step assistance to resolve the whole call tree

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Alexander Kurakin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1802385/alexander-kurakin) thank you for you comment.
An answer to this question is ReSharper | Inspect | Incoming Calls.